# Python: How to hide index when executing

Tags: python, pandas

It's probably something very stupid but I can't find a solution to not print the indexes when executing the code.My code goes:

Reading the excel file and choosing a specific component

```
df= pd.read_excel('Components.xlsx')
component_name = 'Name'
```

Forcing the index to be a certain column

```
df = df.set_index(['TECHNICAL DATA'])
```

Selecting data in a cell with df.loc

```
component_lifetime=df.loc[['Life time of Full unit'],component_name]
print(componet_lifetime)
```

What I get is:

TECHNICAL DATA

Life time of Full unit    20

Is it possible to hide all the index data and only print 20? Thank you ^^

Comment: Adding `.values` (`component_lifetime=df.loc[['Life time of Full unit'],component_name].values`) should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for scalar access *by label*:

```
res = df.at['Life time of Full unit', 'Name']
```

A short guide to indexing:

1. Use `iat` / `at` for scalar access / setting by integer position or label respectively.
2. Use `iloc` / `loc` for non-scalar access / setting by integer position or label respectively.

You can also extract the NumPy array via `values`, but this is rarely necessary.