# Editing specific cells in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm trying to write a function that will enable a user to easily select a specific cell in a pandas dataframe and change its value. For instance, in the dataframe below, I would like to have a user be able to select a cell by date and action, say "2018-03-02" and "Manure", and change the value to "1".

[Sample Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFI7c.png)

I have done this already at 2018-03-02 and "Cutting" by using this code (the dataframe is named q):

```
q.iat[1,1]=1
```

However, I would like to be able to change the cell using something like `q.iat["2018-03-02", "Cutting"]=1`, but am not sure how to do this, as it says `.iat` only recognizes integer postions. Is there something besides `.iat` I could use, or would I need to set a dictionary for every date and every column?

Answer (score 1):

#### [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

Use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) instead of `iat` for efficient scalar label-based indexing:

```
q.at['2018-03-02', 'Cutting'] = 1
```

To [summarise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53838933/9209546):

> A short guide to indexing:
>
> 1. Use `iat` / `at` for scalar access / setting by integer position or label respectively.
> 2. Use `iloc` / `loc` for non-scalar access / setting by integer position or label respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe is indexed with columns names and index. You can set your index with 
[set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):
`df.set_index('date')`
Then use both your date index and 'Cutting' column to change a value with [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):
`df.loc('2018-03-02','Cutting') = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can select columns by name in pandas simply using its name:

`q['Manure']`

In order to select the rows you need an index to uniquely identify them, that could be the date if you make sure its in a format that uniquely identifies it.
Eg:

`q = q.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(q['Dates']))`

Then you can select each cell doing:

`q.loc[<rowIndex>, <colName>]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use DataFrame.loc, this should get you started: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

In your example:

```
q.loc["2018-03-02","Manure"]=1
```